# Javascript recreate multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array stored in a variable named `posts`

```
{ID: 141, categories: ["candy", "fruits", "vegetables"]}
{ID: 142, categories: ["fruits"]}
{ID: 143, categories: ["candy", "vegetables"]}
```

Is it possible to create a new array only with items containing `candy` in the categories?

So the new `posts` variable will have the following array:

```
{ID: 141, categories: ["candy", "fruits", "vegetables"]}
{ID: 143, categories: ["candy", "vegetables"]}
```

Comment: yes it is possible, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `includes()` methods and return new array.

```js
const data = [{ID: 141, categories: ["candy", "fruits", "vegetables"]}, {ID: 142, categories: ["fruits"]}, {ID: 131, categories: ["candy", "vegetables"]}]

const result = data.filter(({categories}) => categories.includes('candy'));
console.log(result)
```